# How to initialize an array in a struct definition?

Tags: struct, rust

How can I set the array values to 0 in this struct? This is obviously wrong. How do I do it correctly?

```
struct Game {
    board: [[i32; 3]; 3] = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];
}
```

In a function this would have been:

```
let board: [[i32; 3]; 3] = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a default value when the struct is initialized? Normally you'd have a constructor function to create the struct with the right defaults.

Comment: Yes, so the board will always be the same when initialized, and later on the values will be changed. @loganfsmyth

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to avoid writing this code again and again? Use a constructor (use it anyway). Do you want to avoid it completely, for some reason (for example, it is more than 3 items and it is verbose)? You can use `Default::default()` for default values (0 for integers) or array initialization syntax for any other constant value (`[[0; 3]; 3]`)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize fields in struct definition because it is *behaviour* while struct must contain only *data*.

This should work:

```rust
struct  Game {
    board: [[i32; 3]; 3]
}

impl Game{
   fn new()->Self{
      Self{
        board: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
      }
   }
}

...
let game = Game::new();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a default value for a struct, you can implement the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait for it.

In the case of a struct containing values that themselves implement `Default`, it is as simple as adding `#[derive(Default)]`:

```rust
#[derive(Default,Debug)]
struct  Game {
    board: [[i32; 3]; 3]
}


fn main() {
    let game : Game = Default::default();
    println!("{:?}", game);
}
```

Alternatively, if your struct is more complex, you can implement `Default` by hand.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=615ee7a46c9c0ea8d27aed5d263dc638)

The advantage of using `Default` over writing a constructor (as in Angelicos' answer) is that:

1. You can use `derive` to implement it
2. Data structures which contain your struct can also use `derive`
3. You can use the `..Default::default()` [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) to specify some fields of a struct, while defaulting the rest.

See also:

- [The Default Trait](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/default.html) in "Rust Design Patterns"
- [Derivable Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-03-derivable-traits.html#default-for-default-values) in "The Rust Book"

Comment: The common pattern is to have both `Default` and `new()` in libraries. For apps, I tend to have only `Default` but this is opinion-based

Comment: 3 is possible with new as well: `S{f1, f2, ..S::new()}`. Actually, you can use any expression which returns this struct.