# How do I declare a type as "one of an enum variant or a None"?

Tags: generics, rust

I simplified the problem to this situation.
Imagine classic tic-tac-toe / tris game.

Players can use X or O.

```
pub enum Symbol {
    X,
    O,
}
```

When thinking about a cell content, one of the 9 positions where user can play, I think, in human terms as

- a cell can contain a `Symbol::X`, a `Symbol::O` or a `None` (when it's not played yet)

How can I represent this content as a type/enum/struct?

Is this a case where we can use Generics? or dynamics? What is the syntax?

### Option 1

```
pub enum CellContent {
    Move(Symbol),
    None,
}
```

### Option 2

```
pub type CellContent = Option<Symbol>;
```

### Option 3 (from accepted answer)

Scale the problem to the above structure, defining something like an `Option<Symbol>`

### Personal note

the option 2, being a type, bring the disvantage that we cannot implement functions fir this type, so we cannot use it because we need compare, etc..

Comment: [Relevant section from the book: defining an enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html). Why not combine that with the `Option` type?

Comment: Please, suggest how.

Comment: The standard [`Option` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/index.html) is commonplace and well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place your `Symbol` enum inside an `Option`, i.e.: `Option<Symbol>`:

```
// your 3x3 table
let mut table: [[Option<Symbol>; 3]; 3] = Default::default();
```

Initially, all the cells in the `table` will be `None`. Then, playing:

```
table[1][1] = Some(Symbol::X);
table[1][2] = Some(Symbol::O);
```

---

Alternatively, you could follow an intrusive approach by defining `Symbol` instead as:

```
pub enum Symbol {
    NotPlayedYet,
    X,
    O,
}
```

That is, defining an additional variant `Symbol::NotPlayedYet`. For this case, you would probably want to implement `Default` for `Symbol` to default to `Symbol::NotPlayedYet`:

```
impl Default for Symbol {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Symbol::NotPlayedYet
    }
}
```

Even more concise, as of [Rust 1.62](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1620-2022-06-30), you can achieve the same by just [deriving `Default`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/94457/) on the `Symbol` enum if you add `#[default]` to its `NotPlayedYet` unit-like variant:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub enum Symbol {
    #[default]
    NotPlayedYet,
    X,
    O,
}
```

Play it this way:

```
let mut table: [[Symbol; 3]; 3] = Default::default();

table[1][1] = Symbol::X;
table[1][2] = Symbol::O;
```

Comment: It was exactly what I am trying ! Side question: can I use None instead of Default::default() or must I explicitly declared 9 times it?

Comment: @realtebo https://stackoverflow.com/q/69920061

Comment: I think it's more suitable to call `default()` on the `[[Option<Symbol>; 3]; 3]` than using a literal. `Option<Symbol>` implements `Default` and therefore so does `[[Option<Symbol>; 3]; 3]`.